# I want to implement interaction with .Net variables in python code.Is there any way to replace scope.Set() scope.Get() of pythonnet?

Tags: python, c#, .net, python.net

There may be multiple writes and reads to variables in a python runtime.Like:

```
# int myint=1
a=NetCore.Get(myint)
b=a+2
NetCore.Set(myint,b)

# myint=3
a=NetCore.Get(myint)
c=a+1
NetCore.Set(myint,c)
# return myint=4
```

Thank you!

Comment: How is this related to the C programming language? Do you perhaps meant to use the C# tag instead? Please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), then [edit] your question to fix problems with it and improve it.

Comment: Sorry,my fault.

Comment: You need to clarify why can't you just work with Python variables. Otherwise your question does not make sense, as .NET methods do not have scopes you can access from outside of the method itself. Are you sure you are not talking about static properties/fields?